# Alternative to the work "pick-up line" and or "ice breaker"

Tags: word-request

I'm searching for a word which does have the same meaning as a pick-up line or an ice breaker but without the implication or intention of dating.

A simple word which means the begin of a conversation, the "first approach".

I don't even know how to call it in my native language (German) which makes it incredible hard to search for an English word.

EDIT: It is about a personal conversation and no business matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **opener** or **introduction**.

- He came over and gave us his opener about his products.
- By way of introduction she described her journey and how pleased she was to be here.

Also

- He came over and gave us his **pitch** about the products (baseball metaphor, also common now in UK marketing/advertising/sales)
- His **opening gambit** was to talk about the introductory offer.  (Chess metaphor, implies cunning)

Many would not know the baseball and chess origins of those phrases, and use them nonetheless.

NB: *ice-breaker* carries social connotation of breaking down shyness, often for groups.  *Pick-up line* (UK *chat-up line*) has sexual connotation.